# how do I install gwtbootstrap3 tutorial?

Tags: gwt, uibinder, gwt-bootstrap, gwtbootstrap3

i am extremely new to gwt and I need to change an existing application to gwtbootstrap for the templates with uibinder.

I've googled for basic installation instructions. Where do the files go after you download.
from https://github.com/gwtbootstrap3/gwtbootstrap3/tree/master/gwtbootstrap3

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don`t have Maven

1) Download the JAR file and add it to the classpath
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.gwtbootstrap3/gwtbootstrap3

2) Inherit the GwtBootstrap3 module in your GWT module:

```
<module>
    <inherits name="org.gwtbootstrap3.GwtBootstrap3"/>
    ...
</module>
```

3) Use the widgets in your UiBinder XML:

```
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui="urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder"
             xmlns:g="urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui"
             xmlns:b="urn:import:org.gwtbootstrap3.client.ui">

    <b:Container>
        <b:PageHeader>Yay buttons!</b:PageHeader>

        <b:Button>Some button</b:Button>
        <b:Button type="DANGER" size="LARGE">Dangerous button</b:Button>
    </b:Container>

</ui:UiBinder>
```

Comment: The "b" namespace doesn't resolve for me and as a result the page is blank. Is any other step necessary to make the namespace resolve correctly?

Comment: If you're using Eclipse, sometimes it struggles to see the imported dependency. I suggest the usual cleaning (Project > clean)